# How to split comma and get string in to javascript array?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, split

I have the following code:

```
 var array = 'hello,test'

 for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     const result = array.split(',')[i]
     console.log(result)
  }
```

I am getting:

```
hello
test
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I want to get `['hello', 'test']`

Comment: You do not want to iterate over the length of the array (`array.length`) here. Just split it once. No need for a loop.

Comment: You can do it this way....

    var array = 'hello,test';
    var result = array.split(',');
    console.log(result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

`const result = array.split(‘,’);`

The way your solution works:

1. You get the length of your string and start a loop
2. It starts from index 0
3. The split splits correctly, you read the 0th index: `hello`
4. Then you read the 1st index: `test`
5. You can not over or underindex an array (object based entity) so the other indexes will be undefined

Just simply use the split method. :)